# Wrapping Sentences within <p> Tags with <span>'s, But Keep Other Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, html-parsing

To give you an idea of what I need, I have been using the below code to parse content within

tags and wrap each sentence within  tags so I can then interact with sentences on a page.

```
$('p').each(function() {
        var sentences = $(this)
            .text()
            .replace(/(((?![.!?]['"]?\s).)*[.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g, 
                     '<span class="sentence">$1</span>$3');
        $(this).html(sentences);
    });
```

However, the following line demonstrates my problem:

```
<p>This is a <a href="#">link</a> and it is removed with the above code! Here is another sentence.</p>
```

Nested tags such as <a>, <img> etc...within <p> tags that I'm searching through are removed with the code that I'm using. I need to keep these tags intact, so the content stays the same within the <p> tags.

I need:

```
<p><span class="sentence">This is a <a href="#">link</a> and it is removed with the above code!</sentence><sentence>Here is another sentence.</sentence></p>
```

After reading [this barn-burner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) about parsing HTML with regex, I've concluded that I need to use a combo of an HTML parser of some sort to traverse through sub-tags within a <p> tag, and then use a regex to find the sentences. I think the regex I have listed above should work for most of my uses, if that helps.

So: how should I do it?

Comment: Why have you asked the same question again?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556598/splitting-html-content-into-sentences-but-keeping-subtags-intact

Comment: I am in the process of closing the other question, because it needs to go in a completely different direction.

Comment: I'll ask you the same question again here. So, what are you expecting for something like this? '<p>This is a sample of a "." inside <a class="some.thing" href="#">some element. What</a> is your expected result?</p>'

Comment: Do not use a regular expression to parse HTML, it just doesn't work.

Comment: That's a great case I hadn't considered. The only logical thing I can think of for my use-case is to include _both_ sentences in the span tags. Additionally, I don't think this call will pop up often enough for it to be a big deal at this point.

Comment: @RobG that is why I included this caveat in the question. I'm trying to think of some way to use DOM parsing to somehow make things work. Or maybe I need to loosen my constraints somehow.

Comment: Ok, this then?, '<p>We'll make it simpler, <a class="emphasis" href="#">What would I do in this case?</a> I really need to <span class="bold">think about it!</span> what do you think?</p>'

Comment: It looks like we could just wrap the sentences in a span that appear within a subtag in '<p>'. That seems to be the best style.

Comment: So how would the above sample look once wrapped? You really need to have some test cases that show the before and after, so that we are certain as to how you want to deal with them. This is an interesting question, and fairly difficult too. But, I would really advise adding said test cases to your question, otherwise I very much doubt that anyone will give this a look. You need to be specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? Care to share it with us?

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to [tokenise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) language, reliably, into sentences and that is without the added complexity of throwing html into the equation. There are some applications etc out there that attempt to deal with [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), an example would be the [Stanford Tokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml) with runs on Java (not Javascript)

And as people keep mentioning, a regex is not the solution to this problem, language is not regular so don't expect a Regular Expression only solution.

There is a question here on SO, [Basic NLP in CoffeeScript or JavaScript — Punkt tokenizaton, simple trained Bayes models — where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721173/basic-nlp-in-coffeescript-or-javascript-punkt-tokenizaton-simple-trained-bay) Which I think summarises things fairly simply for Javascript.

Anyway, to at least give you a little something that you could play with, I knocked up a little code for you. This works reasonable well until the markup/language begins to resemble anything slightly complex or different, but ultimately fails the mark by a long way. But, it may be enough for what you need, I don't know.

CSS

```
.emphasis {
    font-style: italic;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.emphasis.bold {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.unidentified {
    background-color: pink;
}
.sentence0 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.sentence1 {
    background-color: green;
}
.sentence2 {
    background-color: red;
}
.whitespace {
    white-space: pre;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    var rxOpen = new RegExp("<[^\\/].+?>"),
        rxClose = new RegExp("<\\/.+?>"),
        rxWhitespace = new RegExp("^\\s+?"),
        rxSupStart = new RegExp("^<sup\\b[^>]*>"),
        rxSupEnd = new RegExp("<\/sup>"),
        sentenceEnd = [],
        color = 0,
        rxIndex;

    sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("[^\\d][\\.!\\?]+"));
    sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*?$)"));
    sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("(?![^\\(]*?\\))"));
    sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("(?![^\\[]*?\\])"));
    sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("(?![^\\{]*?\\})"));
    sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("(?![^\\|]*?\\|)"));
    //sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("(?![^\\\\]*?\\\\)"));
    //sentenceEnd.push(new RegExp("(?![^\\/.]*\\/)")); // all could be a problem, but this one is problematic

    rxIndex = new RegExp(sentenceEnd.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue + currentValue.source;
    }, ""));

    function indexSentenceEnd(html) {
        var index = html.search(rxIndex);

        if (index !== -1) {
            index += html.match(rxIndex)[0].length - 1;
        }

        return index;
    }

    function pushSpan(array, className, string, classNameOpt) {
        if (className === "sentence") {
            className += color % 2;
            if (classNameOpt) {
                className += " " + classNameOpt;
            }

            color += 1;
        }

        array.push('<span class="' + className + '">' + string + '</span>');
    }

    function addSupToPrevious(html, array) {
        var sup = html.search(rxSupStart),
            end = 0,
            last;

        if (sup !== -1) {
            end = html.search(rxSupEnd);
            if (end !== -1) {
                last = array.pop();
                end = end + 6;
                array.push(last.slice(0, -7) + html.slice(0, end) + last.slice(-7));
            }
        }

        return html.slice(end);
    }

    function leadingWhitespaces(html, array) {
        var whitespace = html.search(rxWhitespace),
            count = 0;

        if (whitespace !== -1) {
            count = html.match(rxWhitespace)[0].length;
            pushSpan(array, "whitespace", html.slice(0, count));
        }

        return html.slice(count);
    }

    function paragraphIsSentence(html, array) {
        var index = indexSentenceEnd(html);

        if (index === -1 || index === html.length) {
            pushSpan(array, "sentence", html, "paragraphIsSentence");
            html = "";
        }

        return html;
    }

    function paragraphNoMarkup(html, array) {
        var open = html.search(rxOpen),
            index = 0;

        if (open === -1) {
            index = indexSentenceEnd(html);
            if (index === -1) {
                index = html.length;
            }

            pushSpan(array, "sentence", html.slice(0, index += 1), "paragraphNoMarkup");
        }

        return html.slice(index);
    }

    function sentenceUncontained(html, array) {
        var open = html.search(rxOpen),
            index = 0,
            close;

        if (open !== -1) {
            index = indexSentenceEnd(html);
            if (index === -1) {
                index = html.length;
            }

            close = html.search(rxClose);
            if (index < open || index > close) {
                pushSpan(array, "sentence", html.slice(0, index += 1), "sentenceUncontained");
            } else {
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        return html.slice(index);
    }

    function sentenceContained(html, array) {
        var open = html.search(rxOpen),
            index = 0,
            close,
            count;

        if (open !== -1) {
            index = indexSentenceEnd(html);
            if (index === -1) {
                index = html.length;
            }

            close = html.search(rxClose);
            if (index > open && index < close) {
                count = html.match(rxClose)[0].length;
                pushSpan(array, "sentence", html.slice(0, close + count), "sentenceContained");
                index = close + count;
            } else {
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        return html.slice(index);
    }

    function anythingElse(html, array) {
        pushSpan(array, "sentence2", html, "anythingElse");

        return "";
    }

    function guessSenetences() {
        var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(paragraphs, function (paragraph) {
            var html = paragraph.innerHTML,
                length = html.length,
                array = [],
                safety = 100;

            while (length && safety) {
                html = addSupToPrevious(html, array);
                if (html.length === length) {
                    html = leadingWhitespaces(html, array);
                    if (html.length === length) {
                        html = paragraphIsSentence(html, array);
                        if (html.length === length) {
                            html = paragraphNoMarkup(html, array);
                            if (html.length === length) {
                                html = sentenceUncontained(html, array);
                                if (html.length === length) {
                                    html = sentenceContained(html, array);
                                    if (html.length === length) {
                                        html = anythingElse(html, array);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                length = html.length;
                safety -= 1;
            }

            paragraph.innerHTML = array.join("");
        });
    }

    guessSenetences();
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9WdeF/)

Answer (score -1):

you need to use .html() instead of .text() if you want to keep tags intact. 
Check below code and let me know if it doesn't work out.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sbbYf/)**

```
$('p').each(function() {
        var sentences = $(this)
            .html()
            .replace(/(((?![.!?]['"]?\s).)*[.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g, 
                     '<span class="sentence">$1</span>$3');
        $(this).html(sentences);
    });
```

Comment: Nice try but it fails badly in many ways, a larger data sample will help you find issues. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/d6yjU/

Comment: @Xotic750 the op was not concerned about `regex`. i used op's regex as it is.. ops concerned was `links were getting missing`. 'that is <a>' tag is getting lost because of `.text()` and my solution solves it.